# Use data from one variable in the title of another - javascript

Tags: javascript, variables

Is there any way to use the data from one variable in the declaration of another variable? It is the same concept of coercing strings, just in the variable declaration. For example, if I wanted to create a variable called user1, is there any way to do it somehow like this:

```
var i = 1; // Creates variable with value of 1
var user + i = "John"; // Creates variable with name of user1 (because i has a value of 1)
```

Comment: Would an array work better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like

```
var i = 1;
var username = 'John';
var users = {};
users[username + i] = username
```

And after this you can use

```
users.John1
```

Is this acceptable ?

Comment: I never knew that array indices can be string in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var i = 1; // Creates variable with value of 1
```

Instead of 
     `var user + i = "John";` // Creates variable with name of user1 (because i       has a value of 1) you should 
use:

```
 window['user'+i] ="John";

 alert(user1);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6x0uLbe8/